# JTAG connection to control board

Tags: jtag

I have got a control board with TMS320F2808 DSC. This
control board was designed by someone else. I need now
to connect an emulator XDS100 to mentioned DSC. My
problem is that I don't know where to connect JTAG
connector. There is no 14 pin header on the control
board and I haven't any schematic to this board. Can
somebody give me an advice how could the connection
point for JTAG look like? I have been trying to find
some 14 "holes" organized in "matrix" 7x2 pattern but
without any success. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Protip: JTAG only needs 6 pins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that I don't know where to connect JTAG connector.

There may not be a JTAG connector on the board. Some designers deliberate don't include them (or even the relevant tracks) on production PCB layouts.

> There is no 14 pin header on the control board

That is just one of several "standard" JTAG pinouts - 10 and 20-pin headers are other common types. (I don't think that the TMS320F2808 uses SWD - but if it did, that uses only 2 pins + Gnd, making it even easier to "hide" them amongst other traces on a PCB.) Therefore don't assume you are looking for a 14-pin header, or even any header at all.

> Can somebody give me an advice how could the connection point for JTAG look like?

No, because there is no guarantee what those connections will look like on *your* PCB and, as I said, a JTAG header or connection points might not even be provided on the PCB! If the designer didn't want to make later JTAG connection easy, then they may have deliberately obscured those connections (even if they exist), so we couldn't tell you what they will look like.

You could start by looking for any silkscreen markings on the PCB, with the names of the JTAG signals.

If you supplied photos of the top & bottom of the PCB, then readers here *might* spot something - but might not.

> I haven't any schematic to this board.

Therefore you will need to reverse-engineer some of it.

If the TMS320F2808 on the board is in a QFP package, then it is easy to look at the JTAG pins on the package and see if there are any traces leading from those pins, to test pads or other connection points. If not, then it is possible to carefully solder wires onto the QFP pins themselves.

However if the TMS320F2808 on that board is in a BGA package, then finding any unmarked JTAG traces (if they exist), or finding connection points for the JTAG signals, could be much more difficult and require X-ray or BGA removal techniques, for example.

If you want help from readers here, the next step is for you to supply those photos that I mentioned (clear, close-up, in focus, and taken from directly overhead the PCB), both sides. If that is not possible due to commercial confidentiality, then you may need to pay for someone with reverse-engineering skills to help "in person".

Finally: I don't know the TMS320F2808, but on some ICs it is possible to disable the JTAG pins after programming, as an anti-reverse engineering technique. *If* that applies to that IC, you might find that the JTAG interface is not actually usable.

Comment: SamGibson, thank you very much for your answer. The JTAG must be present on the control board because there is recommended emulator for connection to it (precisely XDS510).

Comment: @Steve - Hi - So you are saying that you have a document which tells you that the XDS510 *can* be connected to your board, but doesn't tell you *where* to connect it on that board?? If so, that seems very strange because other people, like you, will be stuck not knowing where/how to connect the XDS510. I must be misunderstanding something in your story, because it makes no sense to me :-(

Comment: Yes, I have got some text documentation to my PCB. In this document is described recommended JTAG but there is absolutely no mention where to connect the JTAG. I able to find out JTAG signals used from this document. Namely are these signals: TRST, TCK, TMS, TDI, TDO, EMU0, EMU1. I have found 5 holes organized in one row near DSC. There is also one greater hole next to this group and next to it is one hole with the same diameter like the previously mentioned 5 (unfortunately I am not allowed to send you photos of my PCB).

Comment: @Steve - "described recommended JTAG [...] no mention where to connect the JTAG" - That is very strange. "I have found 5 holes" - You can use the techniques that I mentioned, to trace whether they are the JTAG signals or not. FYI EMU0 & EMU1 are not standard JTAG signals. "I am not allowed to send you photos of my PCB" - Of course that prevents me giving you suggestions :-( In any case, I see you did not upvote my answer, so that means you did not find my answer useful anyway and I am adding no value. Therefore I will stop here. I wish you good luck - perhaps someone else can help you more!

Comment: Excuse me SamGibson. I found your answer very useful because you taught me a lot of new about practical realization of JTAG. Thank you very much.